# Thread handling in TCP server in C

Tags: network-programming, pthreads

This is my first post here, so I'd like to say hello to everyone.
I am facing some problems with writing a TCP, I want to have a separate thread that allows user to type quit instruction to terminate process. The problem is that it doesn't seem to be running. The programme pauses on accept and I am unable to pass anything to the thread function.

The thread function:

```
    void *loop_stop()
    {
        while(progr_control != 'q')
        progr_control = getchar();

        return NULL;
    }
```

And the main (I ommited some code I think is not causing problems):

```
   pthread_t thread_id;
   pthread_create(&thread_id, NULL, loop_stop, NULL);

   do
   {

       listen(sock_fd, 5);
       int addr_len = sizeof(client_addr);

       if( (new_sock_fd = accept(sock_fd, (struct sockaddr *) &client_addr, &addr_len)) < 0)
       {
           perror("Problems with incoming connection");
           return -1;
       }
       else
        //here is the ommited part-as I've said this loop stops at accept

    }while(progr_control != 'q');
```

If anyone could please find the bug, or suggest other way of handling with the task, I'd be grateful

Comment: Where is the call to `bind`?  You should not omit code which is relevant, for example `sock_fd` is initialized.

Comment: `accept` will block until an incoming connection is received, at which point it will return with that connection.  In short, it'll never got to the "quit check" because it is blocked.

Comment: The 'bind' it is in the part of code I didn't paste here.

@BrianWhite thanks, I think I'll use simple ctrl+c for quitting insted.

Comment: @WiktorGonczaronek, please add your own answer so this question doesn't sit around on the "unanswered" list forever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Brian mentioned:
'accept' will make the thread wait for incomming connection, so no "quit check" is possible. The alternative is to use ctrl+c to quit instead.